# Watch simulator buttons seems disabled

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm new in Apple Watch and I'm trying to create the first App with XCode6.3. In my Watch storyboard I put a button but when I run the App in the simulator I can't tap the button and seems disabled... what's happen?

Comment: Additional info... If I have 2 buttons in the storyboard I have to click in the second button (under the first) to have the tap on button 1! Like a problem in displaying the watch graphics... the simulator in not aligned with the mac screen.... someone with the same problem?

Comment: another info... If I have 1 button in the window I have to click in the free area below to see the button clicked! Seems the simulator window is not aligned with the mouse of the mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I returned to the previous beta of Xcode and now is all OK. The simulator works fine. Probably for some strange reason in my mac the simulator of Xcode 6.3 doesn't work correctly.
Thank to all

Answer (score 1):

Having similar issue... Sometimes only a portion of the WKInterfaceButton is clickable. Forced to revert back to Xcode6.2 beta5...